# Boost::Variant; Defining Visitor Class

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern, boost-variant

In Java, I am able to define a variable of a generic class without specifying type.

```
class Tree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {}
somewhere-else: Tree tree;
```

I can then read in some object from a file and type-cast it to the class type I desire.

```
tree = (Tree<String>) some object;
```

With `boost::variant` I have begun a variant definition.

```
typedef boost::variant<Tree<std::string>, Tree<int>> TreeVariant; TreeVariant tree;
```

I know I need to specify a `visitor class` but it is not clear from [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html#variant.motivation.solution) how to define it such that I am able to assign to my `tree` variable either `Tree<std::string>` or `Tree<int>`.

I would then like to proceed from there to call member functions of Tree using the variable `tree`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to create a visitor for assigning values to a `boost::variant`. As shown in the [Basic Usage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic) section of the tutorial, you just assign the value:

```
TreeVariant tree;
Tree<std::string> stringTree;
Tree<int> intTree;
tree = stringTree;
tree = intTree;
```

As for calling member functions, you should use a visitor:

```
class TreeVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
  void operator()(Tree<std::string>& tree) const
  {
    // Do something with the string tree
  }

  void operator()(Tree<int>& tree) const
  {
    // Do something with the int tree
  }
};

boost::apply_visitor(TreeVisitor(), tree);
```

You can also return values from a `static_visitor`, like so:

```
class TreeVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
public:
  bool operator()(Tree<std::string>& tree) const
  {
    // Do something with the string tree
    return true;
  }

  bool operator()(Tree<int>& tree) const
  {
    // Do something with the int tree
    return false;
  }
};

bool result = boost::apply_visitor(TreeVisitor(), tree);
```

Comment: Where would I call boost::apply_visitor? Is it supposed to be a member function of the visitor? I am uncertain about this.

Comment: `boost::apply_visitor` is a free function in the `boost` namespace. The last line in the code example shows how to call it.

Comment: Depending on your code, you could also make TreeVisitor have a template member function operator(), which accepts any type of Tree.  This might be useful if the operations do not need to be aware of the data type within the tree.

Comment: @reima How could I make it so that boost::apply_visitor allows me to return a bool through a function operator such as `bool operator() (Tree<std::string>& tree) const`;

Comment: @Mushy I've updated my answer with an example for returning values from a `static_visitor`.

Comment: @reima One last question.  If I desire to pass two parameters into into a function operator such as `void operator() (Tree<int>& tree, int some_val, long some_initial_index);`, how am I passing in the arguments so the right function is called?

Comment: @reima I think `boost::apply_visitor(boost::bind(TreeVisitor(),tree, val, initialIndex));` may do the trick but not sure ... discovered that from a detailed search.

Comment: @Mushy Add a constructor to `TreeVisitor` which takes the additional parameters and stores them in member variables. Then you can access them from `operator()`.